# Reality Kit – Custom 3D Anchor Types

Tags: augmented-reality, realitykit

In RealityKit there are custom anchor types. The Scene has anchors and the anchors have entities anchored to them, hints the name. with RealityKit it has face anchors, horizontal surface anchors, vertical surface anchors, and image anchors.

My main question is revolving around the idea that there is face anchors. With face anchors it is detecting a face (3D Shape) and the tracking it to be able to use it as an anchor point to attach entities. I'm currently working on an app that having the ability to be able to use custom 3d models as anchors would be invaluable.

Short summary in the app I'm working on developing I need to be able to measure the surface area of a wall in it using RealityKit, If I can make custom 3d Anchors types I'll be able to have the app automatically detect the corners of the wall and place anchors in them and from there it is as easy as using RealityKit's Measuring functions from the coordinates of the anchors. I've done some digging online and I'm honestly not finding too much about making custom anchors but I figured if anyone would know it would be this community. Thank's you's <3

I've tried placing anchors manually however I've never had enough consistence with just tracking for it to measure more then 2 meters at a time unlike the measuring app that comes default on the iPhone that can measure 20-30 feet and not require A) both the anchors to be on the screen at the same time and B) the anchors to not have to be placed from 3-6 feet distance away from the phone, the most I've gotten working is not impressive honestly :P